# What is the contrapositive of this case

Tags: logic

What is the contrapositive of this case:

If $f:X→Y$ is a continuous surjection bewteen separable compact metric spaces, where $X$ has dimension $n$ and $Y$ has dimension $m$, then there is a point $y∈Y$ whose preimage contains at least $n−m+1$ points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contrapositive of $A \rightarrow B$ is $\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A$.

In your example, we have to "parse" the complex sentence according to the "if *_*, then ..." form.

We have that :

> $A :=$ "$f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous surjection bewteen separable compact metric spaces, where $X$ has dimension $n$ and $Y$ has dimension $m$"

and ;

> $B :=$ "there is a point $y \in Y$ whose preimage contains at least $n−m+1$ points".

Thus, the contrapositve will be :

> > *if* **not** "there is a point $y \in Y$ whose preimage contains at least $n−m+1$ points, *then* **not** "$f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous surjection bewteen separable compact metric spaces, where $X$ has dimension $n$ and $Y$ has dimension $m$"

or, in a slightly more palatable form :

> > *if* "**not** exists a point $y \in Y$ whose preimage contains at least $n−m+1$ points, *then* "$f : X \rightarrow Y$ is **not** a continuous surjection bewteen separable compact metric spaces, where $X$ has dimension $n$ and $Y$ has dimension $m$".